# PostgreSQL - existence of index causes hash-join

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-execution-plan

I was looking at the `EXPLAIN` of a natural join query of two simple tables. At first, the postgresql planner is using merge-join. Then, I add index on the join's attribute, and it causes the planner to use hash-join instead (and, with sequential read of the data!).
So my question is: why is the existence of an index causes an hash-join?

**Additional data & code:**

- I defined two relations: R(A,B) and S(B,C). (without primary keys or
  such).
- Filled the tables with few lines of data (~5 each, such that there are common values of the attribute B in R and S).
- then executed:

```
EXPLAIN VERBOSE SELECT * FROM R NATURAL JOIN S;
```

which resulted

```
Merge Join  (cost=317.01..711.38 rows=25538 width=12)...
```

and finally, executed:

```
CREATE INDEX SI on S(B);
EXPLAIN VERBOSE SELECT * FROM R NATURAL JOIN S;
```

which resulted

```
Hash Join  (cost=1.09..42.62 rows=45 width=12)...       
    Seq Scan on "user".s  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=4 width=8)
```

Comment: Why? Because the hash join is cheaper and faster. Just compare the cost estimates.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name then why didnt it use it in the first place, when there was no index for S? (it is iterating sequentially over the tables in the two cases)

Comment: If you want more details on the execution plan use `explain (analyze, buffers)` instead of a plain `explain`

Comment: Because *as a side effect*, the index causes statistics to be collected, (which also results in a better estimate for the number of rows)?

Comment: thanks @joop . I guess that it may be this.